Which (godzilla/dinosaur) Monster movie is this?
I know there are about 35 of them out there. I watched it long ago, so not even sure if it is colour or black and white. since I am not sure if it is Godzilla, I am calling it monster.
What I do remember about the climax:

A group of people would be carrying a young monster on a copter or something ( sorry, there are chances this might be from some other film )
There would be 2 giant monsters,  both would be defeated by giant robot.
Just when people thought everything is over, one flying monster would fly a bit and fall on the other monster.
both monsters would merge and then stronger monster would defeat the giant robot.

Can anyone tell me the name of the movie I am talking about?

Sounds a bit like an almagation of sever Godzilla movies, although I'm not 100% sure. #1 happened in a Godzilla movie, #2 as well. #3 I'm not sure and #4 is nothing I really remember.

Godzilla vs. MechaGodzilla 2, (1993).

The young Baby Godzilla then lets out the loudest roar it can make,
  and the sound travels across the battle field to a fallen ally. From
  under a pile of rubble, Fire Rodan calls back feebly and lifts it's
  self from the ground, attempting to fly to it's distressed "brother".
  MechaGodzilla, however, has no intention of letting the pterosaur
  escape and quickly and easily shoots it down. Rodan lands on
  Godzilla's colossal corpse, and it appears that the two monsters will
  lie dead together. However, the flying monster has one last trick to
  play. As it lays its head on Godzilla's spines, a glowing powder-like
  substance begins to fall around the fallen Monster King. Inside
  MechaGodzilla, Miki realizes that Rodan is transferring his life
  energy to Godzilla. She watches her screen in amazement as Godzilla's
  sacral brain begins to heal itself. Outside, Rodan's body disappears
  as it sacrifices itself so that its "sibling" might live. Several
  seconds later, Godzilla's eyes open, and the creature rises again.
  With energy swarming around him, he lets out a roar of triumph.
  MechaGodzilla, however, is in trouble.


Ahhh! I completely misinterpreted the "merge". :) I was like "What? I can't remember any monster consisting of more than one actual creature."
